# How to change windows explorer view by keyboard?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

Is there a keyboard shortcut to switch to a specific view in windows 7 explorer, e.g. "details", "list", "large icons" etc?

Or do I have to use the mouse to change the view via dropdown menu "Change your view" / toggle views by clicking the icon (which does not toggle through all of the views).

Why I want this: if I navigate to a folder Windows guesses which view might be the best. Sometimes it is right, sometimes it is wrong. Then I want to quickly change, e.g. to "list" to see more files, or to "details" to see columns, or "to extra large icons" to get thumbnails. I think this is quicker via keyboard than via mouse.

**Edit**

I have accepted the sort of obvious answer, using multiple shortcuts to remote control the hidden menu. Currently I am using an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script, inspired by an [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/84716/why-does-windows-xp-explorer-search-sometimes-switch-to-icons-view/84721#84721) to a related question:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass
; alt+1 list
; alt+2 details
; alt+3 large icons
; alt+4 extra large icons
!1::Send !v{down 5}{enter}
!2::Send !v{down 6}{enter}
!3::Send !v{down 2}{enter}
!4::Send !v{down 1}{enter}
#IfWinActive
```

With this I can switch the views I use with alt+1 to alt+4. (Note that the script in the linked answer makes Explorer look for files containing the 'v' character. I fixed that.)

Both solutions have one disadvantage in common: showing and hiding the menubar leads to visible flickering. To fix this the menubar would have to be displayed permanently. Or maybe AutoHotkey knows some tricks to execute a menu command without making the menubar visible first. But I don't know about that.

Comment: Answer in Windows 10 19041: `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `1`. Use 1..6 for every type of view.

Comment: @JesusIniesta Doesn't work for me in Win v2004 (Build 19041.388). However, for me, `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`#` (# = 1..8) as mentioned in [another comment](https://superuser.com/a/1292524/448998) is working...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What about ALT + V + D for details, ALT + V + L for list, etc?

Comment: For international users, replace the `V` and the `D` in `Alt, V, D` by the first letter of View and Details in your language. In French, the shortcut is `Alt, A, D`

Comment: it's a shame but i don't think it works for windows 8

Comment: Doesn't work for Win 10 either

Answer (score 62):

In Windows 8 (And later versions) you can use the following shortcuts for View modes:

**<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + 1** Extra Large 
**<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + 2** Large Icons 
**<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + 3** Medium Icons 
**<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + 4** Small Icons 
**<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + 5** List 
**<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + 6** Details 
**<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + 7** Tiles 
**<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + 8** Content

In Windows 7 for English exhibition language you can use the the following:

**<kbd>ALT</kbd> (Left) + <kbd>V</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>** = Extra large icons
**<kbd>ALT</kbd> (Left) + <kbd>V</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>** = Large icons
**<kbd>ALT</kbd> (Left) + <kbd>V</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>** = Mediom icons
**<kbd>ALT</kbd> (Left) + <kbd>V</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>** = Small icons
**<kbd>ALT</kbd> (Left) + <kbd>V</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>** = List
**<kbd>ALT</kbd> (Left) + <kbd>V</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>** = Details
**<kbd>ALT</kbd> (Left) + <kbd>V</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>** = Tiles
**<kbd>ALT</kbd> (Left) + <kbd>V</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>** = Content

Comment: It is Ctrl + Alt + [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] for me on Windows 10.

Comment: @OmarTariq, I'm on Windows 10 and neither Ctl+Shift+[1–8] nor Ctrl+Alt+[1–8] work :(

Comment: @OmarTariq How weird, it's Ctrl-Shift-# for me on Windows 10. What W10 version are you on? Surprising that MS would change this suddenly.

Comment: @Coldblackice I can't confirm this at the moment as I do not actively use Windows 10 any more, only Mac and Linux, sorry guys.

Comment: It is `CTRL + SHIFT + [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` for Windows 10 Pro, 20H2 too.`CTRL + SHIFT + 6` for "Details", `CTRL + SHIFT + 2` for "Large Icons" as Ricardo Bohner says in his answer for Windows 8 (and later versions).

Answer (score 4):

*There's a lot of confusion in the answers and comments to this question, but hopefully this will be a somewhat definitive answer for Windows 10.*

---

## Windows 10 keyboard shortcuts for folder views

The weird truth seems to be that across editions/versions/builds of Windows 10, there are two different keyboard shortcuts for folder views in active use:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>NUMBER</kbd>

*or*

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>NUMBER</kbd>

Most tech blogs tend to list the Shift variant, making it the de-facto "official" one, while many commenters exclaim that the Alt variant is the only one that works for them. It's hard to tell exactly what factor is responsible for the issue, since many users on the same editions and versions report needing to use different shortcuts.

Unfortunately, since Windows 10's own "full list" of keyboard shortcuts [doesn't even include](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec) the folder view shortcuts, it seems that the most definitive evidence of this phenomenon is the following brief note from a [TenForums guide](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/34119-change-folder-view-layout-windows-10-a.html#option6), which lists the "official" shortcut before adding:

> Some people report they must press Ctrl + Alt instead of Ctrl + Shift.

There's also this answer in a [Microsoft Community question](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files-winpc/shift-ctrl-numbers-thumbnail-view-shortcut-in-file/0df7747a-41dc-4903-8d63-c278bed8c165), which to date has about 40 other users in agreement:

> I'm having the same problem on one of (the many) Windows 10 machines I work on. I have found that Ctrl + Alt + Numbers works like Ctrl + Shift + Numbers should but this makes things very confusing when moving between machines.

For the record I personally had to use the Alt variant, running Windows 10 Enterprise, version 20H2.

---

### Full list of Ctrl+Alt+NUMBER shortcuts

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> - Extra Large view 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> - Large Icons view
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> - Medium Icons view
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> - Small Icons view
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> - List view
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> - Details view
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>7</kbd> - Tiles view
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>8</kbd> - Content view

Comment: Really helpful background info, thanks for sharing. It's bizarre how split this seems to be, however, making me wonder if there's some sort of geographic modifier switch, like perhaps some languages need differing keyboard modifier access, and thus W10 dynamically chooses which modifier route based on that. I wonder if it could also be some sort of A/B testing by Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

You can use <kbd>Strg</kbd> (Control on US keyboards) + Scrolling Wheel. With this combination you can switch between the views. It isn´t a keyboard shortcut, I guess, because you need to use the mouse but maybe it will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Not really what I am looking for though: it takes *many* spins of the wheel to get to a specific view (which is what I asked). Also, if I already use the mouse I might just as well select the view directly ;-)

Comment: Note that ctrl+scroll does not allow switching _to_ detail view, only _from_ it. I ended up here because I wanted a fast way to switch back to detail view when I accidentally do just that.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi Regarding a fast way to switch, see my answer if you're on Windows 10. With regards to Ctrl+scroll though, I can confirm it does scroll through and back the whole range of folder views so it is possible to use it to switch from *and to* detail view, although it is cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

In Win 8 : ctrl + Alt + <1,2,3,4,5,6..etc> will change the file explorer view.

In win 8.1, 10 : ctrl + shift + <1,2,3,4,5,6..etc> will change the file explorer view.

I learnt this from this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxVo8chgq6A

Thanks!

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Comment: While I'm fine with you posting a duplicate answer. This is someone just trying to help DavidPostill, the answer doesn't work in Windows 10. At least not Windows 10 1809 :(

Comment: @selva - The question was about Windows 7 not Windows 10.

Comment: It's Ctrl + Alt for me on Windows 10 v1909 in agreement with a comment to Ricardo's answer.

Answer (score -1):

For me, on the Surface I bought in January 2018, it is CTRL-SHIFT-#, where # is 1, 2, 3, 4... etc.  When # is 1, it is Extra Large, and then it goes down in size from there.  I guess you have to do some trial and error depending on what machine and OS you're using.

Comment: How is this better than Ricardo Bohner's answer?

Comment: Ricardo did not refer to Win 10.  Omar T. commented on Ricardo's answer but gave a different key combination.  Only my post tells users that CTRL-SHIFT-# is a potential key combination for Win 10.  Specifically on the Surface.

Comment: This doesn't work in Windows 10 1809

Comment: Works for me in Win v2004 (Build 1904.388) whilst the [above mentioned](https://superuser.com/questions/185124/how-to-change-windows-explorer-view-by-keyboard#comment2303837_185124) `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`#` doesn't work for me...